# Bad Cyrillic output of Cucumber test result when using Gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber, cyrillic

When I run my Cucumber scenarios with Gradle configuration in IDEA, I get this:
[image: Bad output of case names]

But when I run tests with JUnit Run Configuration in IDEA, names display normally.

Console output is the same in both cases.

Scenarios are written in Russian, I can't show them cause of security restrictions.

Comment: Please try adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` into "Help | Edit Custom VM Options" and restart IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [y.bedrov comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61136477/bad-cyrillic-output-of-cucumber-test-result-when-using-gradle?noredirect=1#comment108246863_61136477).

Adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` into "Help | Edit Custom VM Options" and then restarting an IDE solves this problem.

An alternative solution, which I used before:

change "Run tests using:" from `Gradle` to `IntelliJ IDEA`

in "File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like non-UTF-8 characters interpreted as UTF-8.

Try to force Gradle to use UTF-8 during build:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Setting of the encoding system property for tests might also help:

```
test {
    systemProperty "file.encoding", "utf-8"
}
```