# Intellij Idea, Java, no russian letters displaying correctly, even with manually setting the encoding to UTF-8. What's going on?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I want to get the text from the txt file and print in terminal.
The Russian letters won't display correctly.

I did the next things to fix the problem

> 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34717160/14048134
> 2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36932975/14048134
> 3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61205022/14048134
> 4. go to Help | Edit Custom VM Options... and add (restart IDE is
>    needed):
>    -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
>    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Here's my code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(new String(everything.getBytes(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

No matter what I do, the Russian letter's won't be displayed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After all, no Russian letters are displayed correctly, but the Latin ones and numbers are correct.

How can I fix this problem? Any ideas?

UPDATE 1

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt",StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        String everything = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(everything);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
```

This one doesn't work too.

UPDATE 2

Here's the console settings.

[image]

There is no benefit from this.

UPDATE 3

Expected result (the original text): "Кстати, в Индонезии есть часть страны называемой Java...Карл, Java!!! Еще и страннее то, что как бы Индонезия кажется таким
родным.... с чего это вдруг?"

Actual result (what is displayed in console): "Кстати, в �?ндонезии есть часть страны называемой Java...Карл, Java!!! Еще и страннее то, что как бы �?ндонезия кажется таким
родным.... с чего это вдруг?"

Comment: Are you sure that `file.txt` *is actually UTF-8 encoded*? Does `System.out.println("\u0416");` successfully print Ж on your console?

Comment: Also: `new String(everything.getBytes(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` is dangerous cargo-cult-level "try to fix this stuff, but don't know how" code that I see frequently but is almost always completely wrong. If you know the encoding, specify it when you create the `FileReader`, but don't try to "fix" strings like this after the fact. And especially when you set `file.encoding` to UTF-8, then it's a pointless, expensive no-op.

Comment: @JoachimSauer System.out.println("\u0416"); doesn't print Ж. It prints the same as the txt file's text. A question mark only.

Comment: Could be that the console encoding within IDEA is not set to UTF-8: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html#console Everything you configured is about how the IDEA *editor* treats files and how the Java VM treats encodings, but something (the IDEA console) must also display the console output.

Comment: @a moment, please. I'll check your link.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I checked it. At first there was "default UTF-8" I set directly to UTF-8. Tried again. There are no detected positive changes.

Comment: Well, just to say *By default, IntelliJ IDEA uses the system encoding to view console output.* (per the link @JoachimSauer posted) What *is* your default encoding?

Comment: Edit your Question to include a small piece of text with a few of your problematic Cyrillic characters that we can copy-paste.

Comment: @BasilBourque Just wait a moment and I'll update my question.

Comment: @BasilBourque and an interesting fact. I created a new txt file with Intellij Idea. Copied that part of the text from the first txt file to this new one and I was negatively surprised. In the console, all letters are displayed incorrectly. I decided to check both txt files with notepad++. For the first one it shows that the encoding is in utf-8, but for the second one - windows-1251. But it's weird. In fact, the UTF-8 one is displaying mostly correctly and the windows-1251 one not showing any correct characters. And all this happens when intellij settings are set to windows-1251, not utf-8.

Comment: I suggest you shorten that example text. Just enough few words to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @BasilBourque I shortened the text.

Comment: What JDK version and vendor are used in the project? Try using the latest IDE build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Answer (score 1):

First try to use method `getBytes(Charset charset)` instead of just `getBytes()` in your line:

```
System.out.println(new String(everything.getBytes(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

This may solve your problem. Also, for diagnostics I would suggest to try convert your string that you think contains russian characters into unicode sequence and see if your string really contains russian characters and your problem is only display problem or that your String doesn't have the right chars to begin with. I wrote my own feature that can easily convert string into unicode sequence and vice-versa. Here how it works:
There is an Open Source java library MgntUtils written and maintained by me that has a Utility that converts Strings to unicode sequence and vise versa:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)

Comment: I changed encoding to windows1252 everywhere. Now it nearly works. But nearly only, cause in every thousand characters there are from one to three incorrect characters.

Comment: This is not advisable. If your file is encoded in windows1252 read it with that encoding when you create the file reader.

Comment: Hell. I meant windows-1251 not windows-1252.  Now about the file reader. I tried this too BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt", Charset.forName("windows-1251")));  it still works as nearly, not 100%. Some symbols it won't see. For example "�?нтригует" instead of "интригует"

Comment: Use the library That I described in my answer and see what code you have there

Comment: An interesting detail. I dindn't use Maven before. Before trying to realise your advice I did a little test. I created a new project with Maven and replaced my txt file from Gradle based project to Maven one. And with Maven there's no Error if txt file is encoded with windows-1251 and the IDE  is configured to use windows-1251. So, as I see, the problem is in Gradle!

Comment: Why I decided to do a test like that? I had a bad feeling when I saw that "        System.out.println("\u0416"); System.out.println("Жорик Варданов"); "  displays the same question marks which I saw for my txt file. It's weird, isn't it? The settings for both projects. I mean, the encodings in the configuration are the same but for Gradle - there are question marks while for Maven there aren't any problems. I will not write answer to my question yet. At first I want to try to understand what's wrong with Gradle.  But your answer I'll upvote now, because your hints saved my time.